# Typesetting on a diagonal path

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, text, typesetting, path-effects

I've tried a variety of methods of getting the same style of type, setting it on a path, skewing the text after setting it on a path, setting each individual letter, but none are quite right. Is there a relatively more efficient method?

[image]

Comment: It depends on what effect you were trying to achieve. Examples?

Comment: How was skewing not quite right? What was wrong with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create a diagonal line with the pen tool. Use the type on path text tool and type your text.

Select the Path Type object and go Type > Type on a Path > Type on a Path Options to bring up the Type on a Path dialog.

Chose Stair Step and Gravity to control the orientation of the type relative to the path.