# How to stair step text in Photoshop CS3?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, cs3, text-on-path

I don't know how else to word this question. This is literally it.
HOW do I stair step?

I have never heard of such an option, until now, and need a visual guide with screenshots, otherwise I'm lost.

I have diagonal text sitting on a path, but I just don't know how to stair step it.

There is a related question:
[Typesetting on a diagonal path](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49132/setting-text-on-an-diagonal-path). But the solution there is not available in Photoshop.

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49132/setting-text-on-an-diagonal-path

Comment: @ JaneDoe1337 That person doesn't answer the question. They tell the person to use the Stair Step and Gravity control, which I do NOT have.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 this question only talks about Photoshop. Scarlett (and JaneDoe) the answer on that other question uses InDesign which is why you aren't finding it.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, and thanks to that person miserably failing to police my question, I'll never get an answer. I've googled. Utterly nothing comes up in reference to photoshop cs3.

Answer (score 3):

You can still do it in Photoshop, it takes a little more effort than on Illustrator or Indesign. It will not work with just diagonal text.

Activate the grid (Show > Grid) and (View > Snap to Grid) to make the following steps easier.

1. Use the Pen tool (P) to draw a "staircase" Path.
2. Type your text in the staircase: Use a monospaced font (I used Courier in my example), and adjust the tracking until the letters fall horizontally each one on a step.
3. If you want different sized texts, duplicate and convert it to a Smart Object, then just resize the Smart Object. You can then edit the text.

The image below shows my attempt, I turned off the grid so you can see the Path. to create more text just duplicate the first one and edit with the Text (T) tool.

[image: Staircase text in Photoshop]